# Relation normal matrix and characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are normal and they have the same characteristic polynomial. why $A$ and $B$ are similar?($A,B \in {M_n}(C)$)

Answer (score 2):

If the field involved is the complex numbers then $A$ and $B$ are unitarily similar to a diagonal matrix...so if they also have the same characteristic polynomial then they must both be similar to the same diagonal matrix.

Comment: Why do we know that $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable ? Does this follow from the fact that they are normal ?

Comment: @Peter, yes. ${}$

Comment: @Peter look for the "spectral theorem", which says exactly that normal matrices are (unitarily) diagonalizable